# Accessing Navigation Properties in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have a Controller action the receives 2 URL parameters, which are foreign keys for the data model:

```
 public ActionResult Create(SurveyResponseModel surveyresponsemodel, int MemberId, int ProgramId)
        {
            surveyresponsemodel.MemberId = MemberId;
            surveyresponsemodel.ProgramId = ProgramId;
            return View(surveyresponsemodel);
        }
```

Here is the data model:

```
public class SurveyResponseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResponseId { get; set; }

        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public int ProgramId { get; set; }

        // "If yes, what changes did you make? Mark all that apply."

        [DisplayName("Did you make any changes in your practice, research, or administration activities as a result of participating in this CME activity?")]
        public string CmeChanges { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Better patient follow-up")]
        public bool PatientFollowUp { get; set; }

        public virtual SurveyProgramModel SurveyProgramModel { get; set; }

        public virtual PersonModel PersonModel { get; set; }
```

And the Data Model for "SurveyProgramType"

```
 public class SurveyProgramModel
    {

        [Key]
        public int ProgramId { get; set; }

        public int ProgramYear { get; set; }

        public int ProgramStatusId { get; set; }

        public string ProgramTitle { get; set; }

        public int ProgramTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual SurveyProgramTypeModel ProgramType { get; set; }

        public virtual ProgramStatusModel ProgramStatusModel { get; set; }


    }
```

What I want to be able to do in my view, is retrieve the `ProgramTitle` by the URL parameter that is passed for `ProgramId`.  So the view looks something like:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Model.SurveyProgramModel.ProgramTitle
        </div>
```

However, @Model.SurveyProgramModel.ProgramTitle is throwing an exception because it is null.  I'm thinking I have my navigation property set up incorrectly.  Any idea what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you return your view model to the view?

```
public ActionResult Create(
    SurveyResponseModel surveyresponsemodel) //, int MemberId, int ProgramId)
{
    // MemberId and ProgramId arguments do not need to be defined
    // They will be picked up my MVC model binder, since there are properties
    // with the same name in SurveyResponseModel class
    //surveyresponsemodel.MemberId = MemberId;
    //surveyresponsemodel.ProgramId = ProgramId;
    surveyresponsemodel.SurveyProgramModel = new SurveyProgramModel(); // new line
    return View(surveyresponsemodel); // <- return your view model here
}
```

Comment: Whoops!  Good catch, although it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: OK. So now your SurveyProgramModel property is null. You need to initialize it before giving the entire model to the view.

Comment: What would the syntax for that look like?  If I call both models ToList() it wants me to change the model type in my view.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Not really sure what are you trying to accomplish. You just need to initialize your view model and any of its properties before giving it to the view, if you want to use those properties on the view.

Answer (score 0):

without passing the model to the view, you cant access the properties of the model in your view. thats the possible cause of the error.

```
            public ~ActionResult PassModel(DemoModel _model, int id)
             {
              // your code goes here....

             return View(_model);   // pass the model to view ..so you can work on your model 
              }
```

Comment: I did fix this, but it's still getting stuck.